# ColdFusion xml generation displays html tags

Tags: xml, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-8

In a part of my html page I get the request to generate xml document for download. I do it like this:

```
<cfoutput>
<cfsavecontent  variable="xml_podaci">

<PodaciPoreskeDeklaracije>

<PodaciOPrijavi>
<KlijentskaOznakaDeklaracije></KlijentskaOznakaDeklaracije>
<VrstaPrijave></VrstaPrijave>
<ObracunskiPeriod></ObracunskiPeriod>
<OznakaZaKonacnu></OznakaZaKonacnu>
<DatumNastankaPoreskeObaveze></DatumNastankaPoreskeObaveze>
<DatumPlacanja></DatumPlacanja>
<VrstaIzmene></VrstaIzmene>
<JIPD></JIPD>
<BrojResenja></BrojResenja>
<Osnov></Osnov>
<NajnizaOsnovica></NajnizaOsnovica>
</PodaciOPrijavi>

<PodaciOIsplatiocu>
<TipIsplatioca></TipIsplatioca>
<VrstaIdentifikatorIsplatioca></VrstaIdentifikatorIsplatioca>
<PoreskiIdentifikacioniBroj></PoreskiIdentifikacioniBroj>
<MesecniFondSati></MesecniFondSati>
<MaticniBrojisplatioca></MaticniBrojisplatioca>
<NazivPrezimeIme></NazivPrezimeIme>
<SedistePrebivaliste></SedistePrebivaliste>
<Telefon></Telefon>
<UlicaIBroj></UlicaIBroj>
<eMail></eMail>
</PodaciOIsplatiocu>

<DeklarisaniPrihodi>
<PodaciOPrihodima>
<RedniBroj></RedniBroj>
<VrstaIdentifikatoraPrimaoca></VrstaIdentifikatoraPrimaoca>
<IdentifikatorPrimaoca></IdentifikatorPrimaoca>
<Prezime></Prezime>
<Ime></Ime>
<OznakaPrebivalista></OznakaPrebivalista>
<SVP></SVP>
<BrojKalendarskihDana></BrojKalendarskihDana>
<BrojEfektivnihSati></BrojEfektivnihSati>
<Bruto></Bruto>
<OsnovicaPorez></OsnovicaPorez>
<Porez></Porez>
<OsnovicaDoprinosi></OsnovicaDoprinosi>
<PIO></PIO>
<ZDR></ZDR>
<NEZ></NEZ>
<PIOBen></PIOBen>
<DeklarisaniMFP>
<MFP>
<Oznaka></Oznaka>
<Vrednost></Vrednost>
</MFP>
</DeklarisaniMFP>

</PodaciOPrihodima>
</DeklarisaniPrihodi>
</PodaciPoreskeDeklaracije>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfset fajl_novi_naziv = "PPPPDPrijava.xml">
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=#fajl_novi_naziv#" />
<cfcontent type="application/xml;charset=utf-8">
#toString(xml_podaci)#
</cfoutput>
```

So I put all my xml in a variable and create a new xml attachment. This is what the output of the xml generated file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PodaciPoreskeDeklaracije>

<PodaciOPrijavi>
<KlijentskaOznakaDeklaracije/>
<VrstaPrijave/>
<ObracunskiPeriod/>
<OznakaZaKonacnu/>
<DatumNastankaPoreskeObaveze/>
<DatumPlacanja/>
<VrstaIzmene/>
<JIPD/>
<BrojResenja/>
<Osnov/>
<NajnizaOsnovica/>
</PodaciOPrijavi>

<PodaciOIsplatiocu>
<TipIsplatioca/>
<VrstaIdentifikatorIsplatioca/>
<PoreskiIdentifikacioniBroj/>
<MesecniFondSati/>
<MaticniBrojisplatioca/>
<NazivPrezimeIme/>
<SedistePrebivaliste/>
<Telefon/>
<UlicaIBroj/>
<eMail/>
</PodaciOIsplatiocu>

<DeklarisaniPrihodi>
<PodaciOPrihodima>
<RedniBroj/>
<VrstaIdentifikatoraPrimaoca/>
<IdentifikatorPrimaoca/>
<Prezime/>
<Ime/>
<OznakaPrebivalista/>
<SVP/>
<BrojKalendarskihDana/>
<BrojEfektivnihSati/>
<Bruto/>
<OsnovicaPorez/>
<Porez/>
<OsnovicaDoprinosi/>
<PIO/>
<ZDR/>
<NEZ/>
<PIOBen/>
<DeklarisaniMFP>
<MFP>
<Oznaka/>
<Vrednost/>
</MFP>
</DeklarisaniMFP>

</PodaciOPrihodima>
</DeklarisaniPrihodi>
</PodaciPoreskeDeklaracije> </td>
                </tr>
                </table>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is in html tags

```
</td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

that are still present in xml , how do I remove them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you should use [`<cfxml>`](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfxml), not `<cfsavecontent>`. This way you will get a server error when you try to build an invalid XML document.

Next, the sample code you show can never include HTML tags. This means your sample code is not what you really have. You should improve your question.

Also: Indent your code.

```
<cfxml variable="xml_podaci" casesensitive="yes">
  <PodaciPoreskeDeklaracije>
    <PodaciOPrijavi>
      <KlijentskaOznakaDeklaracije />
      <VrstaPrijave />
      <ObracunskiPeriod />
      <OznakaZaKonacnu />
      <DatumNastankaPoreskeObaveze />
      <DatumPlacanja />
      <VrstaIzmene />
      <JIPD />
      <BrojResenja />
      <Osnov />
      <NajnizaOsnovica />
    </PodaciOPrijavi>
    <!-- ... -->
  </PodaciPoreskeDeklaracije>
</cfxml>

<cfset fajl_novi_naziv = "PPPPDPrijava.xml">
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=#fajl_novi_naziv#" />
<cfcontent type="application/xml;charset=utf-8" /><cfoutput>#xml_podaci#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: When I make the changes you argued I get no results at all ...?! Instead of file made in my download folder I get a save file prompt and link url generated html file name....

Comment: I copied the entire line <cfcontent type="application/xml;charset=utf-8" variable="xml_podaci" />

Comment: This is the error that I get 
Attribute validation error for tag cfcontent. 
on line  <cfcontent type="application/xml;charset=utf-8" variable="xml_podaci" />


java.lang.String is not a supported variable type. The variable is expected to contain binary data.

Comment: What version of CouldFusion are you using?

Comment: 9 , but it should work in 8 also , since there are different app installations

Comment: I see. What does `<cfdump var="#xml_podaci#"><cfabort>` give you? If that looks all-right, remove the `variable="..."` attribute and use `<cfoutput>#xml_podaci#</cfoutput>` (`ToString()` should not be necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

At the end what I did is

```
<cfoutput>
<cfxml   variable="xml_podaci">
<PodaciPoreskeDeklaracije>
<PodaciOPrijavi>
<KlijentskaOznakaDeklaracije></KlijentskaOznakaDeklaracije>
<VrstaPrijave></VrstaPrijave>
<ObracunskiPeriod></ObracunskiPeriod>
<OznakaZaKonacnu></OznakaZaKonacnu>
<DatumNastankaPoreskeObaveze></DatumNastankaPoreskeObaveze>
<DatumPlacanja></DatumPlacanja>
<VrstaIzmene></VrstaIzmene>
<JIPD></JIPD>
<BrojResenja></BrojResenja>
<Osnov></Osnov>
<NajnizaOsnovica></NajnizaOsnovica>
</PodaciOPrijavi>
<PodaciOIsplatiocu>
<TipIsplatioca></TipIsplatioca>
<VrstaIdentifikatorIsplatioca></VrstaIdentifikatorIsplatioca>
<PoreskiIdentifikacioniBroj></PoreskiIdentifikacioniBroj>
<MesecniFondSati></MesecniFondSati>
<MaticniBrojisplatioca></MaticniBrojisplatioca>
<NazivPrezimeIme></NazivPrezimeIme>
<SedistePrebivaliste></SedistePrebivaliste>
<Telefon></Telefon>
<UlicaIBroj></UlicaIBroj>
<eMail></eMail>
</PodaciOIsplatiocu>
<DeklarisaniPrihodi>
<PodaciOPrihodima>
<RedniBroj></RedniBroj>
<VrstaIdentifikatoraPrimaoca></VrstaIdentifikatoraPrimaoca>
<IdentifikatorPrimaoca></IdentifikatorPrimaoca>
<Prezime></Prezime>
<Ime></Ime>
<OznakaPrebivalista></OznakaPrebivalista>
<SVP></SVP>
<BrojKalendarskihDana></BrojKalendarskihDana>
<BrojEfektivnihSati></BrojEfektivnihSati>
<Bruto></Bruto>
<OsnovicaPorez></OsnovicaPorez>
<Porez></Porez>
<OsnovicaDoprinosi></OsnovicaDoprinosi>
<PIO></PIO>
<ZDR></ZDR>
<NEZ></NEZ>
<PIOBen></PIOBen>
<DeklarisaniMFP>
<MFP>
<Oznaka></Oznaka>
<Vrednost></Vrednost>
</MFP>
</DeklarisaniMFP>
</PodaciOPrihodima>
</DeklarisaniPrihodi>
<Kamata>
<Porez></Porez>
<PIO></PIO>
<ZDR></ZDR>
<NEZ></NEZ>
<PIOBen></PIOBen>
</Kamata>
</PodaciPoreskeDeklaracije>
</cfxml>

<cfset fajl_novi_naziv = "PPPPDPrijava.xml">
<cffile action="write" file="#expandpath('./PPPPDPrijava.xml')#" output="#xml_podaci#"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
alert("XML generated on location : #expandpath('./PPPPDPrijava.xml')#");
</script>

</cfoutput>
```

Since I couldn't find a way to avoid html tags when generating xml file as attachment I decided to write a file on server and latter offer a link for that file ...since the app is used by one person...